# Activity not starting and opening onto black screen

Tags: android, android-activity

Activity A starts Intent for Activity B which is a video selector.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 20);
```

In onActivityResult, we start another Activity C passing the selected video path

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 20) {
                Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                String absPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedVideoUri);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CuttingActivity.class);
                i.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(absPath)));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

During use, Activity A successfully opens Activity B. When one clicks on a video, the application freezes, and a couple of seconds later opens a black screen. The onCreate method of ActivityC is never being called. I thought that Activity A was blocking Activity C from starting, so I called finish() like so

```
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

This solved my problem, but I could no longer go back to Activity A as it no longer existed, and I need to be able to do that.

Also, in another area, Activity A directly opens Activity C, this works as expected with no black screens.

P.S Activity A is showing a camera feed. Perhaps the UI thread is too busy?

Activity A

```
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Any errors, when it shows black screen?

Comment: No errors. I have just checked and after calling startActivity which should start Activity C, the onResume method of Activity A is called?!

Comment: 1. Are there any launch modes set to your activities?
2. Did you debug your app, and track which lifecycle methods of activity C are actually called? Are all of onCreate onStart onResume called?

Comment: @Mohru Activity A contains an intent-filter, I have edited it into the post. Yes and none are called, after startActivity(intent for Activity C) the onResume method of Activity A is called and nothing of Activity C (which it should call the onCreate of Activity C)

Comment: @Mohru I would love to be ablee to step through the startActivity execution to see where the exact issue is but I can't as it is byte code.

Comment: onResume being called in Activity A is a normal behavior, even mentioned in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent) Maybe the onResume in Activity A does something that block the UI? Maybe there is some kind of a race condition between resuming Activity A and starting Activity C?

Comment: @Mohru Yes you're right. onResume in Activity A does nothing other than call super.onResum() and a log statement (for my debugging). I think your hypothesis of a race condition might be true, as Activity A has no problem starting Activity C in the other scenario. Do you have any suggestions as to how I might identify/deal with that race condition?

Comment: If onResume in Activity A does nothing, then there shouldn't be any race condition. What happens if you comment out starting Activity C in onActivityResult? I suspect you'll still get a black screen, and that it's connected to not proper handling of the camera. Am I correct? Also, if Activity C is not even created, then probably something is wrong with your intent?

Comment: I'm not sure if `i.setData(...)` is used correctly here. What are you trying to achieve with it? Why not use `i.putExtra` ?

Comment: @Mohru Comment out starting activity C does not get a black screen, it resumes Activity A successfully. I don't think there is anything wrong with the intent as if I call finish() on Activity A then the intent works to start Activity C. But again, I can't call finish() on A, I need it to stay alive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212026/discussion-between-mohru-and-joe-doe).

Answer (score 0):

This question is partly solved, a workaround was to create run the intent for activity C after a delay, to allow Activity A time to resume. This can be done through a handler or ASyncTask. Something occurs when trying to resume Activity A and start Activity C at the same time, what that is, is unknown.